# Magento 1.9 : Sending E-Mail after Customer was created via API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

I created an `API` for a customer, who **needs to create new user accounts**.

The user accounts can be created, after the process finished, then I would like to send an `E-Mail` to the created user, with their login details.

Is there a way to achieve this?